# Varnish 3.0.2 problems with POST requests

Tags: post, request, submit, varnish

We use a Varnish 3.0.2 Frontend Cache for multiple Typo3 Websites through a Loadbalanced Amazon AWS Environment. Everything works fine, but a contact form, which submit the informations with Method POST, does not work as expected. 
I fill out the form and press submit, the browser starts progressing, but returns to the form and hold my putted Information. If I do the same on the Backend PHP Webserver, everything works fine for the Post. So I think there is some issue with my default.vcl. I hope here are some Varnish experts, who can help a Varnish newbie.

```
backend default{
    .host = "10.0.0.10";
    .port = "80";
}

acl ClearCache {
    "localhost";
    "10.0.0.10";
    "10.0.0.96";
}

#acl purge {
#   "localhost";
#   "10.0.0.96";


#}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }

    set req.backend = default;

    if (req.request == "POST") {
        ban("req.url == " + req.url);
        set req.http.X-Test = req.url;
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.request == "BAN") {
    if (!client.ip ~ ClearCache) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }

    # This option is to clear any cached object containing the req.url
    ban("req.url ~ "+req.url);

    # This option is to clear any cached object matches the exact req.url
    # ban("req.url == "+req.url);

    # This option is to clear any cached object containing the req.url
    # AND matching the hostname.
    # ban("req.url ~ "+req.url+" && req.http.host == "+req.http.host);

    error 200 "Cached Cleared Successfully.";
    }

    if (req.request != "GET" &&
        req.request != "HEAD" &&
        req.request != "PUT" &&
        req.request != "POST" &&
        req.request != "TRACE" &&
        req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.request != "DELETE") {
        return (pipe);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        return (pass);
    }
    if(req.http.host ~ "typo3.lygie.de"){
        ##TYPO3-Backend nicht cachen
        if (req.http.cookie ~ "be_typo_user"){
            ##Inhalten löschen wenn Shift+reload gedrückt wird, aber nur bei eingeloggtem user (Backend-Cookie)
            if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
                set req.ttl = 0s;
                ban("req.url == " + req.url);
                return (pass);
            }
        }
        else{
            ##Cookies von TYPO3-Seiten löschen
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        }
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.ttl = 12h;
    set req.grace = 24h;
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|swf|js|css|txt|gz|zip|rar|bz2|tgz|tbz|html|htm|pdf|pls|torrent)$") {
            set beresp.ttl = 48h;
    }

    if (req.url ~ "/typo3") {
    }else {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with `return(pipe)` before. My solution was the easy one. Just do a `return(hit_for_pass)` in `vcl_recv` and then a `return(deliver)` in `vcl_fetch` on the same conditions. It's not a pretty solution, but it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often you don't need to track users via php (after submitting a form e.g.) any further.
Try clearing PHPSESSID cookie if you don't need to react depending on the data inside.

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "PHPSESSID"){
          remove req.http.Cookie;
}
```

I am a newbie to varnish so I am still thinking about any negative side-effects

- watch out if using session based ajax.
- PHP based tracking might make some trouble.
- more ideas anyone?

(Might seem offtopic but I had the exact same situation and solved it that way.)

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but gold. This version is still used.
I have the same version of varnish, and I had 503 when i do a POST.
If you have this problem (yesterday and today):
Notes: Inside vcl_recv In case PUT/POST/DELETE do a return(pass), if you need invalidate the cache do a ban()
First try determinate if that 503 is generated by timeout with

```
backend default{
    .host = "10.0.0.10";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 300s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
```

Second try remplace

```
return (pipe);
```

with

```
return (pass);
```

because don't work well.
Remember: varnishlog is your best friend.